# How to schedule an event in python without multithreading?

Tags: python

Is it possible to schedule an event in python without multithreading?
I am trying to obtain something like scheduling a function to execute every x seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html)?

Comment: If it is exactly what you are looking for, push the I-Love-Your-Answer button.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of `signal.alarm` and a signal handler for `SIGALRM` like so to repeat the function every 5 seconds.

```
import signal

def handler(sig, frame):
   print ("I am done this time")
   signal.alarm(5) #Schedule this to happen again.

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)   

signal.alarm(5)
```

The other option is to use the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module that comes along with Python but I don't know whether it uses threads or not.

Comment: Yet another useful module I've never noticed before; thank you for that. It looks like `sched` runs a classic "run loop", which means you provide it with a bunch of functions that are intended to be called at scheduled times, and then turn control over to `sched.run()` to handle the scheduling and callbacks. It doesn't seem to use threads, or in fact be thread-safe. It also doesn't seem to handle any events other than timeouts.

Answer (score 2):

Sched is probably the way to go for this, as @eumiro points out. However, if you don't want to do that, then you could do this:

```
import time
while 1:
    #call your event
    time.sleep(x) #wait for x many seconds before calling the script again
```

Comment: Is this what you want? This would block your application for `x` seconds completely not allowing it to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Without threading it seldom makes sense to periodically call a function. Because your main thread is blocked by waiting - it simply does nothing.
However if you really want to do so:

```
import time

for x in range(3):
    print('Loop start')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Calling some function...')
```

I this what you really want?

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is not what he wanted. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html):

> Celery is an open source asynchronous
>   task queue/job queue based on
>   distributed message passing. It is
>   focused on real-time operation, but
>   supports scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are
>   executed concurrently on one or more
>   worker nodes. Tasks can execute
>   asynchronously (in the background) or
>   synchronously (wait until ready).

and a code example:

> You probably want to see some code by
>   now, so here’s an example task adding
>   two numbers:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task 
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

> You can execute the task in the
>   background, or wait for it to finish:

```
>>> result = add.delay(4, 4)
>>> result.wait() # wait for and return the result 8
```

This is of more general use than the problem you describe requires, though.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: Thanks for the catch. I did not notice that when I cut and pasted the code from the celery site that the `@task` part was incorrectly formatted.